# What could cause my furnace and Outlets to go out at the same time circuit breaker not tripped

Tags: electrical, receptacle, furnace

My furnace will lose power and I will lose power in the bathroom that shares the wall with the furnace but I will also lose power to the outlet in my kitchen next to my sink in my laundry room that's hooked up to my dryer but not the outlet that hooks my washer up and then the outlet that's in my bathroom on the other side of the house along with the light it all happens at the same time no circuit breakers tripped it will go off for a few hours and usually kick back on within two or three hours it's as if there's no power running to the furnace or those Outlets or either bathroom but they're all on different circuit breakers

Comment: What country?  For example, in the US, it is typical to have the 110v circuit breakers split into two groups such that each group can lose power.  But that wouldn't be true in a country with 220v.  You also might consider including a picture of your breaker box and identifying which breakers control outlets that are on versus off.

Comment: I would suspect GFI outlets but those have to be reset manually.

Comment: Can you post a photo of your panel please? I have a bad feeling that you're losing a leg of your service...